# How to play a video using JSON in android studio

Tags: android, json

I am having a json parser with video inputs.how to play video using json

http://astrovighnesh.com/admin/videosapi.php

this is my parser, need to play this videos using json

Comment: JSON can't actually play videos. But what you can do is to parse the youtube url and call the youtube app via intent and see if you can feed it the video url of your video :)

Comment: i have not yet tried anything im new to this json so i need proper assistance..

Comment: @maxwellmobile check this ref: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/

Comment: idk you can really try google for starters

Comment: @maxwellmobile first you have to how o parse json in android and then save this url in string and try this demo: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/

Comment: androidbegin link just plays only one video at a instance...i need to play alot of videos..

Comment: add your some related code have you parse the json ?

Comment: i have 100s of videos to play how to add all those 100 video in string file any other way...

Comment: pass  your different url in VideoUrl  @maxwellmobile

Comment: use Arraylist @maxwellmobile

Comment: @maxwellmobile first you parse your json data in android?

Comment: k anyother way is there...

Comment: tanx everybody who showed interest for my question, tanx alot for ur idea and hlp....

Comment: Update your question with the exact requirements, this is too broad to answer.

Comment: @shine_joseph i have mentioned my json parser if u see that u can get my point wat type of code i need to develope oly 2 inputs one is title otr is video url need to develope the code.

Answer (score 0):

Original post [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/android-development-play-youtube-video-in-your-app-cant-play-this-video-and-troubleshooting/).

First you need get the youtube video url, in your case, this is either "d2LAjSBm0lc" or "zUVe4_krJRw".

You also need "YouTube Android Player API", which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

Then create new project with an empty Activity. In the layout XML, add below code:

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id=“@+id/videoView1“
        android:layout_width=“match_parent“
        android:layout_height=“wrap_content“ />
```

In the YourActivity.Java class, change the base class from Acitivity to YouTubeBaseActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
             YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
```

In the onCreate() function in your activity, add below code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) 
                     findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}
```

Here you need a developer key, which is saved in the static class DeveloperKey:

```
public class DeveloperKey {
   /**
   * Please replace this with a valid API key which is enabled for the 
   * YouTube Data API v3 service. Go to the 
   * <a href=”https://code.google.com/apis/console/“>Google APIs Console</a> to
   * register a new developer key.
   */
   public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = “abcdedefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz”; 
}
```

Implement the interface YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, 
             YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
         if (!wasRestored) player.cueVideo(“d2LAjSBm0lc”); // your video to play
}
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, 
            YouTubeInitializationResult arg1){
}
```